# TimerCallback function based on Standard Template LIbrary without Boost

Tags: c++, stl, timer

Are there TimerCallback libraries implemented using STL. I can't bring in Boost dependency into my project.

The timer on expiry should be able to callback the registered function.

Comment: IMO, rather than bringing in a library, you might be able to write your own timer quickly and cleanly. Spawn a new thread, repeatedly call your function and then make the thread sleep for some time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no specific timer in the standard library, but it's easy enough to implement one:

```
#include <thread>

template <typename Duration, typename Function>
void timer(Duration const & d, Function const & f)
{
    std::thread([d,f](){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(d);
        f();
    }).detach();
}
```

Example of use:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

void hello() {std::cout << "Hello!\n";}

int main()
{
    timer(std::chrono::seconds(5), &hello);
    std::cout << "Launched\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
}
```

Beware that the function is invoked on another thread, so make sure any data it accesses is suitably guarded.

Comment: Nice solution thank you, however, this works only in `clang`, g++ 4.8.2 says `error: field 'timer(const Duration&, const Function&) [with Duration = std::chrono::duration<long int>; Function = void()]::__lambda0::__f' invalidly declared function type`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Avio: Change the argument to `&hello`, to force a conversion to a pointer type. (I'm not sure whether Clang or GCC is deducing the type correctly here, but that should make both do what you want).